# File upload error in Django

Tags: html, django, flash

Currently working on a site built in Django and i'm getting an issue when they try uploading a file on there PC. In IE it says 'HTTP error' and in Firefox it says 'IO error'. They are using IE 8 and the latest version of firefox with Windows media edition.

It's only on this PC they are getting the issues so i can't see how it would be a permissions thing. Just hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checking you mean its a single computer just having the problem Quote"It's only on this PC they are getting the issues".

Compare the differences between this pc and the other pc that are successful.Your right it probably isn't a permissions problem on your serverside, but it may be a security problem with this pc in question.many things could cause such errors:

Are your successful computers have any differences from window browsers, eg:Mozilla, Chrome ect...Firewalls, User control settings on the computer? 
Its hard to Conclude as companys put custom restrictions on their machines.
and the information you have provided doesnt explain depth.

Also check your error logs on your server through ftp, this may give you an indacation why this task is not successful for the pc in question, theres many factors to consider, have a look and let us Know how you go, also if you manage to solve this please leave an answer for others.

Answer (score 0):

Does PC mean client or server? Are you sure the path you are uploading to exist on the server?